# What's "<?=" operator in C++?

Tags: c++, operators, operator-keyword, min

I came across the following code [here](http://tjsct.wikidot.com/dijkstra), which is from the C++ implementation of Dijkstra algorithm using an adjacency matrix.

```
//read in edges keeping only the minimum
for(int i=0; i<E; i++) {
    int v1,v2,tmp;
    fin >> v1; fin >> v2;
    fin >> tmp;
    adjmat[v1][v2]<?=tmp; // <?= sets left to min(left,right)
    adjmat[v2][v1]<?=tmp;
}
```

Pay attention to the last two lines, which apply operator **`<?=`**. As being commented, the following line

`adjmat[v1][v2]<?=tmp; // <?= sets left to min(left,right)`

will set `left` to `min(left,right)`.

I never see this operator before. I tried the code in VS, it can not compile. What is it? How can it set `left` to be `min(left,right)`?

Comment: What a silly piece of code. The moment you need to explain a non-standard three-character operator in a comment directly following it, is the moment you stop using it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is an old [GCC extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/gcc/Min-and-Max.html); it does what it says in the comment (it's the compound assignment form of the "minimum" operator). This is not standard C++.

The difference between `a = a < b ? a : b` and `a <?= b` is that the latter only evaluates each operand once.

---

In modern standard C++, I believe you could write an "assign the minimum" algorithm like this:

```
auto && __a = a;
auto && __b = b;
if (!(__a < __b)) { __a = std::forward<decltype(__b)>(__b); }
```

This should be the body of a macro which has the effect of `a <?= b`, and `a` and `b` are arbitrary expressions, potentially with side effects. Or you could wrap it into a template:

```
template <typename T,
          typename U,
          typename P = std::less<std::common_type_t<std::decay_t<T>, std::decay_t<U>>>
T && clamp_to_minimum(T && a, U && b, P p = P())
{
    if (!(p(a, b))) { a = std::forward<U>(b); }
    return std::forward<T>(a);
}
```

Comment: Can I use it in Visual Studio (C++)? Does it mean the latter will be more efficient?

Comment: @herohuyongtao: "It is a GCC extension" seems pretty definitive ...

Comment: @Jongware: Well, it could also be an extension of other compilers, but I wouldn't know. You can always come up with an equivalent standard piece of code...

Comment: Anywhere I can find more info about this operator?

Comment: @herohuyongtao: I added a link. I believe this has been removed from recent GCCs.

Answer (score 7):

It is equivalent to:

```
adjmat[v1][v2] = (adjmat[v1][v2]<tmp)? adjmat[v1][v2] : tmp;
```

In general:

`a OP ?= b;` <=> `a = (a OP b)? a : b;`

A little example (compiled using MingW2.95 and C-Free IDE on Windows) showing what @Kerrek SB said: the GCC extension evalute operands only once, which it's nice

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f(int x)
{
    printf ("Calling f() with x=%d\n", x);
    return x*x;
}

int main()
{
    int a,b,c;

    printf ("A and B? ");
    scanf ("%d%d", &a, &b);

    c = a;
    a = (a<f(b))? a : f(b);
    printf ("A using ternary operator: %d\n", a);

    a = c;
    a <?= f(b);
    printf ("A using weird GCC extension: %d\n", a);

    return 0;
}


A and B? 3 1
Calling f() with x=1
Calling f() with x=1
A using ternary operator: 1
Calling f() with x=1
A using weird GCC extension: 1
```

Comment: "Conditional operator".